# Significance of "savages" dialogue in American Sniper

Tags: character, dialogue, american-sniper

In American Sniper, there comes a scene where a fellow soldier shows Chris Kyle a piece of jewelry that he bought from Iraq, to which Chris Kyle responds

> How come you buy this from the savages?

I found this dialogue a little odd.

Did Chris Kyle consider the whole Iraq as a savage place, or was this just some weak moment where he uttered words in tiredness and frustration?

Answer (score 4):

Kyle felt the **enemy** were savages, and in that war it was hard to tell who was and wasn't your enemy.  I'm 99.9% positive if you asked anyone who has fought in a war, they'll tell you that they felt their enemy were savages.  You can't step into a warzone and not feel hatred towards your enemy, otherwise you'll hesitate pulling the trigger and some of your fellow soldiers could die due to that lack of action.

**Source:**

[The Truth About American Sniper](http://www.city-journal.org/2015/bc0130mt.html)

Comment: While plenty of soldiers likely do think that, there's also plenty that do not. The Chris Kyle character was merely one that did.

Comment: "The Chris Kyle character"?  You know this was supposedly an autobiographical story, right?  I say "supposedly because it's been determined that parts of it are BS, but Chris Kyle was a real person who did think the enemy were savages.

Comment: Yes, he was a real person. We're talking about the movie, though. I'm also not questioning that he (the character or the real person) thought that. I'm questioning the statement 'if you ask anyone'. Not all soldiers think the same any more than all people do.

Comment: So anyway, I guess the point is that Chris thought the enemy was savage and not the whole country or civilization and by enemy we mean Saddam's regime. Is that correct ?